# Increment/Looping URL with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

1. I Would like to Increment/Looping URL using Selenium WebDriver

   ```
   Ex: 
   Volume 1 :
       www.abc.com/1/1
       www.abc.com/1/2
       www.abc.com/1/3
       www.abc.com/1/4

   Volume 2:
       www.abc.com/2/1
       www.abc.com/2/2
       www.abc.com/2/3
       www.abc.com/2/4
       www.abc.com/2/5
   ```

   Etc..

   ```
      1. Once the Volume 1, Issues 4 Fished moves into Volume 2 and check 
         all issues and moves into Next Volume 3..
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple For loop can be helpful in your scenario. You can do it using Java as follows :

```
 {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/Selenium/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        int i,j;

        for(i=1;i<5;i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<10;j++)
            {
                String url = "https://website.com/"+i+"/"+j+"";
                driver.get(url);
            }
            }
}
```

i is count for your first volume and j is count for issues you have mentioned.
You can define it accoding to your requirements.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: @RSN perfect , enhanced with my code its working perfect, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Read volume count and issue count for each page from test data. Then Iterate using for loops as given below. I have assumed the ReadVoulmentCount method return number of volume and ReadIssueCount method returns number of issues for the page.

```
{
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        int volumeCount=ReadVolumeCount();
        int issueCount=0;

        for(int volumeNo=1;volumeNo<volumeCount;volumeNo++)
        {
            issueCount=ReadIssueCount(volumeNo)
            for(int issueNo=1;j<issueCount;issueNo++)
            {
                String url = "https://website.com/"+volumeNo+"/"+issueNo+"/";
                driver.get(url);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for help.